# Adding spam addresses to SpamHaus and SpamCop DNSRBL

Tags: postfix, spam

I have a Postfix e-mail receiving server setup.

I have applied the following setting in my Postfix main.cf file:

```
    smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  reject_unauth_destination, 
  reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org,
  reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net
  permit
```

for checking the mails with DNSRBL providers.

I want to know if a certain IP address is continuously attacking with spam on my e-mail server, then how can I get it added with the following DNSRBL provider list:

1. Spamcop
2. Spamhaus

thanks in advance.

Ashish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spamcop requires you to [view spam emails](http://www.spamcop.net/anonsignup.shtml) to make sure that they really are spam. I don't think they give you an option to have your mta report spam automatically.

Spamhaus [offers **no** way](http://www.spamhaus.org/faq/answers.lasso?section=Generic%20Questions#103) to report spam to them, neither manually (like spamcop) nor automatically.

Answer (score -1):

I think the reject_rbl_client is what you are looking for:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net
```

Comment: How is this basically different from what Ashish already has mentioned in his question? And how does this *report* the offending IP addresses to different DNSBLs?

Comment: I agree with joschi's comment.